# How to accept raw special characters in a function?

Tags: python, function, tabs, special-characters

I have a function that asks for a delimiter. This can be \t. However, this is seen as a real tab. So if I have this code

```
def example(dataToBeSplit, delimiter):
    return dataToBeSplit.split(delimiter)
example('some\ttext','\t')
```

The input given to example is `example('some\ttext','    ')`

How can I prevent the \t to be turned into a real tab, without having to give \\t to the function?

*if I put four actual spaces it gets filtered out, so see -four spaces- as four real spaces

---

edit:

Ok so from zefciu's answer I now do

```
def example(dataToBeSplit, delimiter):
    return dataToBeSplit.split(repr(delimiter))
example('some\ttext','\t')
```

But still wondering if there isn't a way to do this in the

```
def example(dataToBeSplit, delimiter):
```

part

Comment: Can you state your problem more clearly?  I know Python string manipulation, escapings, and encodings pretty well, but I have no idea what you're asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see the string in the form it can be accepted by python, use repr():

```
>>> print repr('some\ttext')
'some\ttext'
```

Answer (score 0):

User the `r` string literal:

```
example('some\ttext',r'\t')
```

Comment: that's the same as using \\t but I dont want to give raw data, I want it to take whatever it gets and see it as raw data

    I see now my double \\ got filtered out

Comment: But "it" doesn't "get" what you claim it does. If the user types in a backslash followed by a t in response to an `input` prompt, then that string will consist of a backslash followed by a t, i.e. `"\\t"` or `r"\t"` if you expressed it in code. If the string is part of the code, then of course you will need some escaping so that Python knows what is part of the string and what is the rest of the code.